# JDBC - não conecta ao banco de dados Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, jdbc

Em **java** eu criei um projeto em que uso o *drive* ***mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar***, neste projeto criei uma classe com um formulário para cadastrar curso e em **mysql** criei um banco de dados chamado `sistema` com uma tabela chamada `curso` com os campos:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então criei o seguinte código dentro do método do botão **Incluir** para cadastrar o curso:

```
    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
if(e.getSource() == BIncluir){
    //procura a classe com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
                try{
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                    //cria uma variável:
                    Connection con;

                    //cria uma conexão com o banco de dados
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/sistema", "root", "");

                    //minha query
                    String query = "INSERT INTO curso (cod_curso, nm_curso, tipo_curso, carga_h, cod_instituto) VALUES(?,?,?)";

                    //cria o camando
                    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

                    //seta os valores na string de inserção
                    stmt.setString(1, CodCurso.getText());
                    stmt.setString(2, Txt1.getText());
                    stmt.setString(3, Txt2.getText());
                    stmt.setString(4, CargaHoraria.getText());
                    stmt.setString(5, CodInstituto.getText());

                    //executa o comando no banco de dados 
                    stmt.executeUpdate();

                    //fecha o comando e a conexão com o banco de dados
                    stmt.close();
                    con.close();

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) { //tratador de erro do comando Class.forName
                    System.out.println("Não foi possível encontrar a classe");
                } catch (SQLException ex) { //tratador de erro do comando con = DriverManager.getConnection
                    System.out.println("Não foi possível conectar ao banco de dados");
                }
```

Fiz testes de conexão antes de incluir a query e ele estava conectando, mas parou de conectar quando inclui esta parte do código que cria e executa a query:

```
//minha query
                String query = "INSERT INTO curso (cod_curso, nm_curso, tipo_curso, carga_h, cod_instituto) VALUES(?,?,?)";

                //cria o camando
                PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);

                //seta os valores na string de inserção
                stmt.setString(1, CodCurso.getText());
                stmt.setString(2, Txt1.getText());
                stmt.setString(3, Txt2.getText());
                stmt.setString(4, CargaHoraria.getText());
                stmt.setString(5, CodInstituto.getText());

                //executa o comando no banco de dados 
                stmt.executeUpdate();

                //fecha o comando e a conexão com o banco de dados
                stmt.close();
                con.close();
```

Quando aperto o botão Incluir ele mostra a mesnsagem que defini no try catch: `"Não foi possível conectar ao banco de dados"`
Por favor quem souber me ajuda!!!! :0

Comment: Manda imprimir a exception (`ex`) no lugar dessa descrição

Comment: Você pode mudar a mensagem fixa do SQLException para ex.getMessage() para podermos ver o real erro?

Comment: coloquei assim mas n aparece nada:  catch (SQLException ex) { 
                ex.getMessage();
            }

Comment: Coloca System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

Comment: ok arrumei agora sim, esse é o erro q apareceu: Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3).

Comment: Beleza, então vou escrever a resposta aqui pra ficar registrado

Comment: ha achei o erro, é no values

Comment: tenho 5 registros e no values coloquei só 3 VALUES(?,?,?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3).

Sua query tem 3 parâmetros e você está tentando definir 5 parâmetros. O ideal é que no tratamento de erro você utilize a mensagem retornada pela exceção, assim não ocultará o erro real.

```
System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
```

Comment: OBRIGADA!!!!!!!